# Opendaylight Argon: How can I manage an L2 network?

Tags: opendaylight, openflow

I am getting into ODL and would like to know how to manage a switch network as a first step. I have seen that in previous versions there are features that allow to activate the option but in the last versions this option is not included. So I don't see how to configure a L2 network with latest ODL.

I know I could use previous versions to take advantage of this feature but I would like to learn how to configure my own code to manage the network with OpenFlow to be able to customize the network management later.

In other controllers like Ryu or ONOS I have been easy to find L2-switch example codes, but in this case I am having a hard time finding them to understand the integration that is done with ODL. If you have any example it would also be of great help.

Thanks for your help